# Can I use a on premise sql database as the back end for a SharePoint 2013 App?

Tags: 2013

All the information that I can find on accessing SQL from a SP web application involves using Azure - an option my company does not want to use. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. It does need to be accessible from wherever the app resides, however.

Comment: Thanks, Derek. Could you provide any links to some material that would provide an outline of the steps?

Comment: The only thing that should be different is the connection string. Everything else should be exactly the same. What is the information you have that is telling you otherwise? What version of Visual Studio are you using, and what project template are you using?